# php classes -- expectation

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new at object oriented programming with php. I have a problem. I wrote a code but that does not work. I know it's easy yet I wonder what's wrong with it. I take the following error :

[image]

```
<?php

class connectDB
{
     $connection;
     $server= "localhost";
     $userName = "root";
     $password = "";
     $select;
     $dbName = "profiles";


     public function connect()
     {
        $connection = mysql_connect($server,$userName,$password);
        $select = mysql_select_db($dbName,$connection);
     }

      public function query()
      {
            $result = mysql_query($query); 
             if (!$result) { 
                 echo 'Bağlantı Hatası: ' . mysql_error(); 
                 exit;  
            }
      }

      public function end() 
      { 
          mysql_free_result($connection); 
      } 
}


?>
```

When i try to use it in another file , i take this error now :(
[image]

Comment: Please, please, *please* do not create yet another horrible wrapper around the devastatingly prehistoric "mysql" family of functions.  Join the rest of us in this century by using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.  You should also [review the PHP documentation on objects](http://php.net/language.oop5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is not supposed to do something (yes, it does something through methods), it is **primarily** there to **represent** something - an object of the real world. The "thing" being represented is the one doing something.

The name

```
class connectDB
```

suggests otherwise.

You should learn some OOP principles from a book before attempting to "just group functions". That's not what classes are for.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249835/book-recommendation-for-learning-good-php-oop

In the end you would have either a class `Connection` or a class `Database`.

And, since you've joined the "OOP club", you should use PDO.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)?

It's simple, powerful and ready.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `access modifier` for each property just like how you do it with the methods. Simply add something like `public`, `private`, or `protected` right before the variable name.

Also I noticed you're doing something wrong to when trying to access the property of the class within the function. For example:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($server,$userName,$password);
```

Should be

```
$this->connection = mysql_connect($this->server,$this->userName,$this->password);
```

BTW, most people would usually just pass the server, username, and password as parameters of the constructor instead of putting it inside the class. Not saying that it's obligatory though...

Answer (score 2):

This should work.
(class property must have access modifiers)

Anyway if you using OO take a look in Mysqli (object oriented lib) for accessing MySql database.

**EDIT:**
Code fixed.

```
class connectDB
{
     private $connection;
     private $server= "localhost";
     private $userName = "root";
     private $password = "";
     private $select;
     private $dbName = "profiles";


     public function connect()
     {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->server,$this->userName,$this->password);
        $this->select = mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->connection);
     }

      public function query($query)
      {
            $result = mysql_query($query); 
             if (!$result) { 
                 echo 'Bağlantı Hatası: ' . mysql_error(); 
                 exit;  
            }
      }

      public function end() 
      { 
          mysql_free_result($this->connection); 
      } 
}

// usage
$o = new connectDB();
$o->connect();
$o->query("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE");

?>
```

Comment: thank you but in another file i wrote require 'connectDB.php'; and create and object  $connectDB = new connectDB();
            $connectDB->connect(); like that but it says Notice: Undefined variable: server in C:\xampp\htdocs\googleAnalytics\GAPI\connectDB.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: userName in C:\xampp\htdocs\googleAnalytics\GAPI\connectDB.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\googleAnalytics\GAPI\connectDB.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: dbName in C:\xampp\htdocs\googleAnalytics\GAPI\connectDB.php on line 16

Comment: to access instance variable in connect method you should use: $this->server, $this->userName .. etc

Comment: i only want to use my method :S

Comment: i want to use it in another php file when i do that it says undefined :S

Comment: Where exacly says it's undefined ? (which line) (Did You use code from my answer ?)